# How can I programmatically cancel a Dataflow job that has run for too long?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Apache Beam on Dataflow through Python API to read data from Bigquery, process it, and dump it into Datastore sink.

Unfortunately, quite often the job just hangs indefinitely and I have to manually stop it. While the data gets written into Datastore and Redis, from the Dataflow graph I've noticed that it's only a couple of entries that get stuck and leave the job hanging.

As a result, when a job with fifteen 16-core machines is left running for 9 hours (normally, the job runs for 30 minutes), it leads to huge costs.

Maybe there is a way to set a timer that would stop a Dataflow job if it exceeds a time limit?

Answer (score 4):

It would be great if you can create a [customer support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/) where we would could try to debug this with you.

> Maybe there is a way to set a timer that would stop a Dataflow job if
>   it exceeds a time limit?

Unfortunately the answer is no, Dataflow does not have an automatic way to cancel a job after a certain time. However, it is possible to do this using the APIs. It is possible to [wait_until_finish](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.4.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowPipelineJob.html#waitUntilFinish-org.joda.time.Duration-)() with a timeout then cancel() the pipeline.

You would do this like so:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
p | ... # Define your pipeline code

pipeline_result = p.run()  # doesn't do anything
pipeline_result.wait_until_finish(duration=TIME_DURATION_IN_MS)
pipeline_result.cancel()   # If the pipeline has not finished, you can cancel it
```

Comment: I deeply appreciate that you have looked into this issue. I must say, I had never experienced a stuck job until I added that ParDo writing asynchronously into Redis. But I haven't experimented with writing only into Redis, without writing into Datastore.

However, I've now switched to writing into Couchbase through ParDo, instead of using Redis + Datastore, and I haven't experienced any stuck jobs since then yet.
I will raise a support ticket if the same issue occurs again.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To sum up, with the help of @ankitk answer, this works for me (python 2.7, sdk 2.14):

```
pipe = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
...  # main pipeline code
run = pipe.run()  # doesn't do anything
run.wait_until_finish(duration=3600000)  # (ms) actually starts a job
run.cancel()  # cancels if can be cancelled
```

Thus, in case if a job was successfully finished within the duration time in `wait_until_finished()` then `cancel()` will just print a warning "already closed", otherwise it will close a running job.

P.S. if you try to print the state of a job

```
state = run.wait_until_finish(duration=3600000)
logging.info(state)
```

it will be `RUNNING` for the job that wasn't finished within `wait_until_finished()`, and `DONE` for finished job.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this technique will not work when running Beam from within a Flex Template Job...

Comment: Hello   are there any other alternatives for job kicked off via Flex template? i have jobs that at odd times runs for over 10 hours eating up my bills..

Answer (score -1):

The run.cancel() method doesn't work if you are writing a template and I haven't seen any successful work around it...

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58006665/2227743) rather than a new answer.